# lsnrctl not working on Oracle 19c Database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

No matter how I edit, set and export my env variables, `lsnrctl start` won't work.

Have already double checked all sets for `$ORACLE_HOME`, `$ORACLE_BASE` and `$ORACLE_SID`, included home/oracle/bin in my `$PATH`, but listener keeps returning error messages....

My variables are set as follows:

```
export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP

export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=dbserver
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=cdb1
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
export ORA_INVENTORY=/u01/app/oraInventory
export ORACLE_SID=cdb1
export PDB_NAME=pdb1
export DATA_DIR=/u02/oradata

export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/oracle/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

Error message:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 08-DEC-2020 14:06:27

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12545: Message 12545 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00515: Message 515 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Any hint? Thank you.

`echo $ORACLE_HOME` followed by  `lsnrctl status` :

[image]

Output for `ls -l $ORACLE_HOME`

```
[oracle@dbserver ~]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME
total 0
[oracle@dbserver ~]$
```

Output for `ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/network/mesg`

```
[oracle@dbserver ~]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/network/mesg
ls: cannot access '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Well, we don't know for a fact that the environment was correctly set _in the session_ in which you issued your 'lsnrctl' command. As far as that goes we don't even know what lsnrctl command you issued - start?  status? services? reload?  (and most of the env vars you show are not in play for this error).  I'd want to see the complete session log ... commands and responses .. for the following commands:  'echo $ORACLE_HOME' followed immediately by 'lsnrctl status'.  Please update your question to show that.

Comment: One other thing, if your lsnrctl command was issued from a shell script launched from cron, you profile is not referenced.  Scripts launched from cron are responsible for setting their own environment vars.

Comment: Thank you for your support. As I stated on the first sentence of my post, the command is 'lsnrctl start'. When I did the echo you sugested, the return was: "/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1 lsnrctl status"

Comment: Sorry, my speed reading overlooked that detail in your opening sentence.  Now, I gave you TWO separate commands:  1) 'echo $ORACLE_HOME', and 2) 'lsnrctl status'.  It appears you issued one command: 'echo $ORACLE_HOME lsnrctl start'.  And I asked you to update your original question, so that you could show it formatted and in context.

Comment: @EdStevens, take a look, please. I think everything follows as you asked

Comment: Ok next I'd want to see the output of these TWO commands: 1) 'ls -l $ORACLE_HOME', and 2) 'ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/network/mesg'.  And screen shots of terminal sessions are particularly hard to read.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to learn how to copy text from a terminal session and paste it - code formatted - into your opening question.

Comment: @EdStevens, done!

Comment: Please post output from `set | grep ORA | cat -v`. `ls -ld $ORACLE_HOME`, `ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/network/`. Check your profile settings file where you set the variables to ensure it is plain text `cat -v settigs.env > s1; cat settings.env >s2; diff s1 s2` should give 0 differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I noticed a installation problem. The ORACLE_HOME directory didn't have all the expected files, directories and structure.

Eventhough, even making a clean new install, I still had to edit my listener.ora file and change the hostname for the server ip address.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. As for your listener.ora, you really don't need it at all. Without it, the listener will happily start with all default values, and that is good for the vast majority of installations.  Just make sure you have a proper entry for the server name in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: "This has come to be a real journey."  Those are the ones from which we learn the most! :-)